# How are domain names stored?

Tags: server, dns, ip, web-hosting, nameservers

I have three domains hosted with GoDaddy, these three domains point to the digital ocean name servers, where I can manage the DNS records, I can still access the domains through my GoDaddy account and GoDaddy still change me yearly for these domains.

I was wondering how these domain names are still available on GoDaddy, if they are pointing to the digital ocean name servers? and how can GoDaddy still charge me to host the domains if they are pointing to another name server?

I'm finding it hard to understand the general architecture of this whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GoDaddy is in this case the service provider who has rented the domain for you from the responsible registrar. [A domain name registrar is an organization that manages the reservation of Internet domain names.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar)

By changing the name server you only change an entry of the domain that shows which name server is responsible for resolving the domain. If you have set your domain's NS record to the Digital Ocean name servers, Digital Ocean's name servers are now responsible for resolving the domain names. [Here is a HowTo](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean)

If your domain is pointing to another name server, then the Dommain is still in the administration area of GoDaddy, for which you have to pay GoDaddy.

I am not a digital ocean expert, but I don't think you can host / rent a domain directly there. So you've done everything right.

[An Introduction to DNS Terminology, Components, and Concepts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-dns-terminology-components-and-concepts)